# BUG in Excel CountIF function

Tags: excel, formula, countif

I am having problems with the CountIf Function in Excel.

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)
```

The A column consists of these items:

```
0107791489614255200011140926107503100513

0107791489614255200011140926107503100457

0107791489614255200011140926107503100518

0107791489614255200011140926107503100503

0107791489614255200011140926107503100519

0107791489614255200011140926107503100444

0107791489614255200011140926107503100521

0107791489614255200011140926107503100438

0107791489614255200011140926107503100449

0107791489614255200011140926107503100443

0107791489614255200011140926107503100501

0107791489614255200011140926107503100455
```

the formula results to 12, even though these set of strings are not really the same at all. It counts these strings as similar strings, I am thinking this is related to its string length?

What do you guys think? I appreciate your help.

Comment: It's version 14.0.7128.5000

Comment: I would highly recommend not to use such IDs which contain only numeric digits. As you have seen there are problems with them because often they get into numeric context when they should not. This is not only within calculations but also within data transfer. If they would start with a letter, then those problems would not occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preceding the strings with a single apostrophe will not remedy the situation. COUNTIF is designed to interpret data as numerical, where possible, irrespective of the datatype of the values in question. This is sometimes helpful, sometimes (as here) not.

SUMPRODUCT does not exhibit this property:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(0+($A$1:$A$12=A2))
```

will return 1, as desired.

Regards

Comment: +1, good advice on the COUNTIF - although it does work on Excel2013.

Comment: Ah, apologies. Interesting. Perhaps you could make that explicit in your answer?

Comment: Can I ask you expert opinion about this? I used the SUMPRODUCT function, the idea is that the macro populates cells with this sumproduct function, and now it slowed my macro drastically. when i tried to remove this, my macro went back to being fast.

Comment: Yes. COUNTIF(S)/SUMIF(S) can accept entire columns as the reference with no significant detriment to performance, whereas SUMPRODUCT and CSE formulas, for example, suffer in such cases.

Answer (score 5):

+1, A good question. Not really a bug but a feature!

This is due to Excel implicitly converting the inputs to its internal numeric type **and losing precision** in doing so. Excel's internal numeric type is an IEEE floating point double precision number. (Although it does clever things with formatting and error propagation so it appears to get sums like 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 correct).

As they are so similar they all compare as mutually equal.

One remedy would be to prefix each string with `'` (single quotation) which will prevent the conversion to the numeric type. Then the `COUNTIF` value returns 1. (At least in my version of Excel; 2013).

Comment: Hi. I just tried it but still it doesn't work. I even tried to change the formatting to only read it as TEXT but it's still returning 12.

Comment: Prefix each string with the single quotation. It will then work in all versions of Excel (certainly since Excel 97).

Comment: Yep I tried that, still it returns 12. This is bugging my all day.

Comment: Hum. Let's build up the numbers. Reduce the size of the list to 2. Cut the number of digits down by half until it works. Then introduce the single quotation. See when the break happens. Remember that it's *most unlikely* to be a bug in `COUNTIF`. The Excel developers do have unit and regression tests.

Comment: It breaks down in the 19th digit.. Is there any workaround I can do for this?

Comment: Have you tried the single quotation character before each number? e.g. `'1234` etc.